# To what extent can animagi communicate with other animals?

Tags: harry-potter

In the fourth book, after Voldemort returns and is telling the Death Eaters about his exile, he says that Wormtail (after escaping from Sirus, Lupin, and the trio) transformed into a rat and was informed by other (real) rats about a dark shadow that possessed them (Voldemort). This raises the question of how much a human who is transformed into an animal communication with other animals of its species?

Comment: Good question but I think that was the only instance communication with animals was ever mentioned as far as Animagus form in canon. Hopefully someone can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes beyond simply being able to communicate with one's own "species." Sirius is able to communicate in some form with Crookshanks when he transforms into a dog (PoA, Chapter XIX).

> ‘This cat isn’t mad,’ said Black hoarsely. He reached out a bony hand and stroked Crookshanks’s fluffy head. ‘He’s the most intelligent of his kind I’ve ever met. He recognised Peter for what he was straight away. And when he met me, he knew I was no dog. It was a while before he trusted me. Finally, I managed to communicate to him what I was after, and he’s been helping me ...’
>
> ‘He tried to bring Peter to me, but couldn’t ... so he stole the passwords into Gryffindor Tower for me ... As I understand it, he took them from a boy’s bedside table ...’
>
> ‘But Peter got wind of what was going on and ran for it ... this cat – Crookshanks, did you call him? – told me Peter had left blood on the sheets.'

Mind you, Crookshanks is half-Kneazle, which makes him a great deal more intelligent than the average cat. Nonetheless, the concepts that Sirius and Crookshanks communicate to each other are remarkably advanced.

So I'd say yes, it does appear to be the case that Animagi can communicate complex and abstract ideas with other animals. The fact that Sirius says that he "managed" to communicate with Crookshanks probably indicates that it isn't automatic like Parseltongue.